# MongoDB. Selecting only 1 column from table

Tags: mongodb

I have the following database

```
{"userName":"John Smith", "followers":8075,"body":"my text 1","confirmed":"no"}
{"userName":"james Bond", "followers":819, "body":"my text 2", "confirmed":"yes"}
{"userName":"Julia Roberts","followers":3882,"body":"my text 3","confirmed":"yes"}
{"userName":"Jamal David","followers":6531, "body":"my text 4","confirmed":"yes"}
{"userName":"jane fonda","followers":3941, "body":"my text 5","confirmed":"no"}
```

I need to count number of followers whose name starts with Ja (**case-insensitive**)

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
db.test.find({$and:[{followers:{$gte:0}}, {"userName":{$regex :/^Ja/i}}]})
```

but it gives me bach the whole matching string while I need only the userName. Could you help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add [projection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/) to query

```
db.test.find({followers:{$gte:0}, userName:{$regex :/^Ja/i}}, {_id:0, userName:1})
```

Keep in mind:

- find always returns _id unless you specify `_id:0` in projection.
- $and operation is used implicitly - you don't need it to specify filters for several fields

Comment: Thank you. Works perfectly.